# SQL Server Execution Plan Ambiguity

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

issue - Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
Below is the query in SQL Server

```
SELECT FIELD_VALUE,
  FREQUENCY_COUNT
FROM Table1 IFNV
INNER JOIN Table2 IFV
ON IFNV.FIELD_KEY = IFV.FIELD_KEY
INNER JOIN Table3 IFVSD
ON IFVSD.FUNCTION_KEY       = IFNV.FUNCTION_KEY
WHERE IFVSD.PROFILE_RUN_KEY = 78
AND IFV.FIELD_NAME          = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
AND
  CASE
    WHEN IFV.IS_VIRTUAL = 0
    THEN IFV.RECORD_NAME
    ELSE IFNV.RULE_NAME
  END = 'EMPLOYEES'
  AND FIELD_VALUE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FREQUENCY_COUNT DESC,
CAST(FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC(6,0)) DESC;
```

The issue doesn't happen when there are no tables present in the DB i.e. Tables and data are recently added in the DB.
It happens only when there lot of data present in these tables. (When we clear the DB and recreate everything, this error doesn't comes but sadly we cannot clear the DB and recreate every time). Not sure why it isn't occurring the first time itself

Upon analyzing it further, we found that in SQL Server, it was first doing the Casting operation and then the WHERE clause.

Is there any way to overcome this execution flow without clearing the DB?

[Trying Not Like operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfNsd.jpg)

[UnsortedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q56JX.png)

Comment: The problem most likely lies in your data.  Can you include some data from the `FIELD_VALUE` column?  Also, you might want to change your title, as this question does not seem to have anything do with an execution plan.

Comment: What is your server version? If 2012 or higher use TRY_CONVERT instead of CAST. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The datatype of the FIELD_VALUE is nvarchar. The table has FIELD_NAME, FIELD_VALUE and other columns. Some Data is FIELD_VALUE is "Samson", 102, 104, "RAHUL" and so on...
When the FIELD_NAME is "EMPLOYEE_ID", the FIELD_VALUE data is 102, 104 and all the numeric values. In Oracle it is working fine. It happens only in SQL SERVER

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Different customers might have different versions of SQL SERVER. Not sure what version. Here, I am using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: Got resolved. We had to use "OPTION (FORCE ORDER)" in order to make the SQL SERVER use the correct joining order

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later

```
SELECT FIELD_VALUE,
  FREQUENCY_COUNT
FROM Table1 IFNV
INNER JOIN Table2 IFV
ON IFNV.FIELD_KEY = IFV.FIELD_KEY
INNER JOIN Table3 IFVSD
ON IFVSD.FUNCTION_KEY       = IFNV.FUNCTION_KEY
WHERE IFVSD.PROFILE_RUN_KEY = 78
AND IFV.FIELD_NAME          = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
AND
  CASE
    WHEN IFV.IS_VIRTUAL = 0
    THEN IFV.RECORD_NAME
    ELSE IFNV.RULE_NAME
  END = 'EMPLOYEES'
  AND FIELD_VALUE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FREQUENCY_COUNT DESC,
         TRY_CAST(FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC(6,0)) DESC;
```

Try the following if you are using SQL Server version older than 2012 .

```
SELECT FIELD_VALUE,
  FREQUENCY_COUNT
FROM Table1 IFNV
INNER JOIN Table2 IFV
ON IFNV.FIELD_KEY = IFV.FIELD_KEY
INNER JOIN Table3 IFVSD
ON IFVSD.FUNCTION_KEY       = IFNV.FUNCTION_KEY
WHERE IFVSD.PROFILE_RUN_KEY = 78
AND IFV.FIELD_NAME          = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
AND
  CASE
    WHEN IFV.IS_VIRTUAL = 0
    THEN IFV.RECORD_NAME
    ELSE IFNV.RULE_NAME
  END = 'EMPLOYEES'
  AND FIELD_VALUE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FREQUENCY_COUNT DESC,
         CASE   WHEN FIELD_VALUE NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                THEN CAST(FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC(6,0))
                ELSE NULL 
         END DESC;
```

---

**Edit**

basically it means you are trying to convert a value to numeric(6,0) which is bigger than numeric(6,0) . An easier option will be to use LEFT(FIELD_VALUE , 6) instead of using CAST in your order by clause

```
SELECT FIELD_VALUE,
  FREQUENCY_COUNT
FROM Table1 IFNV
INNER JOIN Table2 IFV
ON IFNV.FIELD_KEY = IFV.FIELD_KEY
INNER JOIN Table3 IFVSD
ON IFVSD.FUNCTION_KEY       = IFNV.FUNCTION_KEY
WHERE IFVSD.PROFILE_RUN_KEY = 78
AND IFV.FIELD_NAME          = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
AND
  CASE
    WHEN IFV.IS_VIRTUAL = 0
    THEN IFV.RECORD_NAME
    ELSE IFNV.RULE_NAME
  END = 'EMPLOYEES'
  AND FIELD_VALUE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FREQUENCY_COUNT DESC,
         LEFT(FIELD_VALUE , 6) DESC;
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the suggestion. This I had tried already. Problem with this part is that the IsNumeric part itself was failing giving the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."
That's why we had added the precision and scale during casting

Comment: The main issue is that the the query in SQL SERVER takes all the columns in consideration during the cast operation (even if it's not numeric)

Comment: @harendrapratapsingh try now I have used `NOT LIKE` operator instead of the Isnumeric operator, ISNUMERIC is pretty useless anyway it also interpreters values like 123a1 as numeric values.

Comment: Same errors as earlier. Let me attach the screenshot

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: @harendrapratapsingh basically it means you are trying to convert a value to numeric(6,0) which is bigger than numeric(6,0) . An easier option will be to use `LEFT(FIELD_VALUE , 6)` instead of using `CAST` in your order by clause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this query won't results in sorted order. It's fetching the results in Lexicographically sorted way. Attached the screenshot (UnsortedOutput)

Comment: Got it resolved. I appended the query with "OPTION (FORCE ORDER)" and it worked :)